# Sudden jumps in internet latency

Tags: networking, router, bridge, latency, modem

For the past 2 months I've had some weird hitches on my internet.
Every so often (about 5-15 minutes) I get a single short spike of high latency. Below is a capture of the previous 200 ping results.[image: Graph of ping test]
(PS: I have also pinged other sources, and I notice these hitches significantly when playing games, around 2500ms total typically, all led-lights are lit with the status of a correctly working connection)

**My routing setup is the following:**

1. ISP Modem in Bridge Mode (Inteno DG400PRIME)
2. Personal Router (ASUS RT-AC87U)
3. My Computer (Windows 10)

**I have tried / confirmed the following:**

1. Disconnect my personal router and setup the ISP modem directly. (Works fine, no hitches)
2. Disconnect all other network devices except my computer. (Problem persists)
3. Update personal router firmware (Problem persists)
4. Update settings from suggested posts (https://routerctrl.com/asus-router-keeps-disconnecting-from-internet/)
5. Full factory reset of personal router (Problem persists)

**I have chosen to ignore the following (low probability):**

1. Test replacing cables. (I dont think I have any extras right now)

I'm currently waiting for a new modem from the ISP in the mail, hoping that perhaps the Bridge Mode is somehow not cooperating well any longer. If you know of any articles or forums which contains this type of issue, they would be highly appriciated. I'm not sure if I've searched for the exact correct terms, so I was unable to find anything that sounded exactly like this problem.

Comment: In case it was not completely clear from original description.
I have confirmed that connecting through my personal asus router is at fault. And my tests are attempting to get that into a state that works again.